# An overriding operator-> to delegate method to a member

Tags: c++, c++11, delegates

I have the following struct:

```
template<typename T>
struct S {
std::unique_ptr<T> ptr;

};

S<std::string>* s = new S<std::string>();

s->any_method();
```

How to override `operator->` to `any_method` was called on `ptr`. To be more precise, I would like to:

The expression `s->any_method()` "would be translated to" `s->ptr->any_method()`.

Comment: First your code is wrong, S is template type, then you can't use it that way. Second, there is plenty of such example over the web. Look for c++ operator-> overloading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all,

```
S* s = new S();
```

is not right. `S` is a class template, not a class. You need a template parameter to instantiate an object, such as:

```
S<int>* s = new S<int>();
```

Assuming that is fixed first ...

You cannot use `s->any_method()` when `s` is a pointer.

You can use `s->any_method()` when `s` is object or a reference to an object, if you overload `operator->`.

Here's a minimal example.

```
#include <memory>

template<typename T>
struct S {
   std::unique_ptr<T> ptr;
   T* operator->() { return ptr.get(); }
};

struct foo { void any_method() {} };

int main()
{
   S<foo> s;
   s->any_method();
}
```

Comment: ok, what if I have: `auto x = std::make_shared<S<foo>>() s; x->any_method();`?

Comment: @user10121051, that should work. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Simply return a pointer.

```
template<typename T> struct S {
    S(T &&t): ptr(std::make_unique<T>(std::move(t))) {}
    S(T const &t): ptr(std::make_unique<T>(t)) {}

    T *operator->() { return ptr.get(); }
    std::add_const_t<T> const *operator->() { return ptr.get(); }
private:
    std::unique_ptr<T> ptr;
};
```